# Classifying growth as percent increase.

Tags: mathematical-modeling, applications

So I have been thinking about resource consumption a lot after watching [the most important video you will ever see](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eOykY2SMbZ0). It is pretty long so I will summarize it as follows, the professor makes a strong case for sustainability on the basis that if our fossil fuels are used at an exponential rate we will find ourselves without energy very quickly.

While the argument was a strong one, there was an assumption/narrative being made/forced in the video: that the consumption of our resources is currently exponential.

I did a couple of searches through the internet, but the evidence does not support the claim that our [energy use](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=global+fossil+fuel+consumption) is exponential -that is in developed nations, and on the global scale. In fact the charts seen in all my searches seemed to show a linear growth, as in this chart provided by wolfram of [petroleum consumption](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=global+petroleum+consumption). If I am wrong feel free to send me evidence showing otherwise, as this may just be a very local view of an exponential curve.

This led my mind to wonder about classifying increasing sequences based on their percent growth rates.

Let $f:\mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be an increasing sequence mapping a set of integers $[\alpha,\infty)$ to $[1,\infty)$ in the reals such that $f_0 = f(\alpha)=1, f_1=f(\alpha+1), \ldots, f_n=f(\alpha +n)$

We can then define sequential percent growth between any two consecutive elements in the sequence to be: ${f_n-f_{n-1} \over f_{n-1}} \times100 \%$

As to be expected with an increasing geometric sequence: $ar^0, ar^1, \ldots, ar^n$ where the ratio between any two consecutive terms is r. The percent growth between any two consecutive terms then turns out to be:
${ ar^n -ar^{n-1} \over ar^{n-1}} \times 100 \% = (r-1) \times 100 \%$.

The interesting stuff starts happening when we try to apply this growth definition to other increasing sequences.

So for instance, we find that for $f(x) = x$, the percent growth from one element $f_{n-1}$ to the next $f_n$ is: ${1 \over n} \times 100\%$

With a little more work we can generalize for $f(x)= mx+b$ to find that the percent growth is: ${m \over m(\alpha + n-1) + b} \times 100 \%$

I know enough about math to know that for polynomial the percent growth rates will asymptotically go to zero as n gets large.

I also know about the better curve fitting methods, and know for continuous models we can use calculus, and I have heard of and know very little of big O and little O notation...

What I am wondering is the following:

1) What is this concept I have stumbled upon called? I have done searches related to it, and found nothing. BUT it is too simple to have never been explored before. The search I have done on growth for example have pretty much classified growth into the categories of: linear growth, polynomial growth, logistic growth, exponential growth, and hyperbolic growth.

2) If it is not new, in which course is this taught? I am amazed that such a concept isn't explored more commonly as I think this being used to determine given the % growth of data what sequences may fit the data, and possibly have ways of making interesting theorems about the growths of certain sequences.

3) Am I making a mountain out of a mole hill?

So far I have tried finding the percent growth of sequences of the following other functions as well: Root functions, Logistic functions, hyperbolic functions, factorials, super-exponential functions, and even the Fibonacci sequence.

I apologize if the video is seen with any degree of politicization, that is not my intent. My intent is to be able to determine what can be said about % growth data that is presented to us whether it maybe in population increase, inflation, to examine Neo-Malthusian ideas with a fair and critical lens or whatever.

Comment: What you have observed is that for a polynomial function $f(x)$, you have (in a hand waving sense) $\dfrac{df}{dx} \approx \dfrac{k}{x} f$ as $x \to \infty$, where $k$ is the degree of the polynomial.  It is is that division by $x$ which distinguishes polynomial growth from exponential growth

Comment: But what about other non-polynomial increasing functions mentioned? Like what general statements can we make about other functions and their percent growth, and how could we use this % growth between consecutive elements of a sequence to distinguish functions in general?

Comment: In the same sense, for an exponential function $\dfrac{df}{dx} \approx k f$ for large $x$, while for a logistic function $\dfrac{df}{dx} \approx e^{-x}  f$ for large $x$.  A hyperbolic function never reaches large $x$, but just below its limit $m$ you have $\dfrac{df}{dx} \approx \dfrac{1}{m-x}   f$

Comment: Ahhhhh, ok I see what you mean! However by hyperbolic functions I meant sinh(x), cosh(x), and tanh(x). I wish I would have noticed this in my Analysis classes, thank you!

Comment: $\sinh$ and $\cosh$ grow like an exponential function; $\tanh$ like a logistic function.